# Representar en GoogleMap base de datos con direcciones de calle y número

Tags: php, google-maps, phpmyadmin, google-maps-v3

Estoy interesado en representar en una web con googlemap una base de datos phpmyadmin con información de calles y números de comunidades que están contaminando río y mar en mi ciudad. Dispongo de una lista con calles y números y me gustaría representarlo en googlemap con sus marcadores.

Sigo los pasos marcados en google (combina php, javascript, xml y googlemap): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps?hl=es

El código queda así con el php de dentro para general el XML que después Googlemap deberá interpretarlo. Pero me da el error:

***Error de lectura XML: contenido incorrecto tras un elemento XML del documento
Ubicación: http://localhost/googlemap/google-maps.php
Número de línea 22, columna 1:`<markers><marker name="Hunter Gatherer" address="Greenwood Plaza, 36 Blue St, North Sydney NSW" lat="-33.840282" lng="151.207474" type="bar" /><marker name="The Potting Shed" address="7A, 2 Huntley Street, Alexandria, NSW" lat="-33.910751" lng="151.194168" type="bar" /><marker name="Nomad" address="16 Foster Street, Surry Hills, NSW" lat="-33.879917" lng="151.210449" type="bar" /><marker name="Three Blue Ducks" address="43 Macpherson Street, Bronte, NSW" lat="-33.906357" lng="151.263763" type="restaurant" /><marker name="Single Origin Roasters" address="60-64 Reservoir Street, Surry Hills, NSW" lat="-33.881123" lng="151.209656" type="restaurant" /><marker name="Red Lantern" address="60 Riley Street, Darlinghurst, NSW" lat="-33.874737" lng="151.215530" type="restaurant" /></markers>`***
^

```
    <!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Using MySQL and PHP with Google Maps</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>


<?php
require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");

function parseToXML($htmlStr)
{
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
return $xmlStr;
}

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ('localhost', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // Add to XML document node
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>




  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
      var customLabel = {
        restaurant: {
          label: 'R'
        },
        bar: {
          label: 'B'
        }
      };

        function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.310, -1.974),
          zoom: 14
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
          downloadUrl('https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/mapmarkers2.xml', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
              var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
              var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = address
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
              var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                label: icon.label
              });
              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            });
          });
        }



      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }

      function doNothing() {}
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAHEMCKMKBYqimXwIKJX6AK6Sgm1N-fDJw&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muéstranos con código qué has intentado. Por ahora tu pregunta es muy amplia y no podemos programar algo desde cero pues escapa al alcance de este sitio

Comment: Ya he completado el enunciado con código a ver si me he expresado mejor para que se entienda lo que busco. Básicamente representar en un plano googlemap las direcciones de una base de datos. Saludos y gracias.